# iOS Crash in CLSTerminateHandler()

Tags: swift, xcode, crash

I'm getting this crash from many devices using my app. 
I can't see where is the error since Xcode doesn't select any line in the code and the backtrace of the log is quite confusing for me.
The **Xcode Organizer** selects the error on *CLSTerminateHandler()*, but can see where in my project. 
Here's the crash log:

```
Date/Time:           2020-01-27 14:10:51.6942 +0800
Launch Time:         2020-01-27 14:10:03.8467 +0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.30.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b7670288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766b3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766aadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001c15f0328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bb765ae0 UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
7   StickersCreator                 0x00000001048f3cac main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:19)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b74f4360 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b7670288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766b3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766aadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b79aa7f4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b79aa6d4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bb7fe204 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152 (UIEventFetcher.m:637)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b7adb0a4 __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   StickersCreator                 0x000000010495f918 CLSMachExceptionServer + 100
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7411758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74e9ec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b74051d8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b73598c0 __abort + 112 (abort.c:147)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b7359850 abort + 112 (abort.c:118)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b74b27d4 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b74b29ac demangling_terminate_handler() + 272 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:61)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b741a268 _objc_terminate() + 140 (objc-exception.mm:704)
7   StickersCreator                 0x0000000104972730 CLSTerminateHandler() + 348
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b74bf304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b74bf29c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:87)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b73bf198 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:498)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b73676f8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 684 (inline_internal.h:2484)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b7373fa4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:2525)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b7374770 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128 (queue.c:6628)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740eb48 _pthread_wqthread + 212 (pthread.c:2364)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7411760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74e9c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7406cf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 680 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001b753c7a8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:287)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c646d22c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::uni... + 108 (condition_variable:204)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c6470bfc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 200 (condition_variable:213)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c64708e4 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 12 (Scavenger.cpp:384)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c6471bf0 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, st... + 40 (type_traits:4361)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b7670288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766b3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766aadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   WebCore                         0x00000001bf63317c RunWebThread(void*) + 612 (WebCoreThread.mm:626)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7411758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b7670288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766b3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766aadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c4230c1c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:91)
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001c4281d60 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 204 (CAPThread.cpp:286)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74e9c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7406cf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 680 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c643195c WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 80 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:518)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c6417848 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::Scope... + 2040 (ParkingLot.cpp:596)
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x00000001c3689d74 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184 (ParkingLot.h:80)
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x00000001c368c9a8 std::__1::unique_ptr<WTF::Function<void ()>, std::__1::default_delete<WTF::Function<void ()> > > ... + 168 (MessageQueue.h:153)
6   WebKitLegacy                    0x00000001c368c08c WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 68 (MessageQueue.h:131)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c642f5d4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256 (Function.h:79)
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c6431144 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:200)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74e9c94 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7406cf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 680 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c643199c WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 144 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:541)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c6417848 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::Scope... + 2040 (ParkingLot.cpp:596)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c63f0104 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184 (ParkingLot.h:80)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c63f048c WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>:... + 216 (Condition.h:115)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c642f5d4 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 256 (Function.h:79)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c6431144 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:200)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b7670288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766b3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766aadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001ba9214e8 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 192 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b7adb0a4 __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c8634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b74c7aa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b7670288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766b3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b766aadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001ba9214e8 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 192 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b7adb0a4 __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b740dd8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b741176c thread_start + 8

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7411758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7411758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b7411758 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000020   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000016c60b000   x9: 0x40b3ddf8bf7fe521  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x2e73656c706d6153
   x12: 0x29287974706d652e  x13: 0x636e7566206e6920  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0a27734d4d477469
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000007c000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000007103  x21: 0x000000016c60a970  x22: 0x000000016c60b0e0  x23: 0x0000000000000114
   x24: 0x000000016c60b0e0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x00000000000005ff  x27: 0x00000001ff2f1480
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016c60a890   lr: 0x00000001b74051d8
    sp: 0x000000016c60a870   pc: 0x00000001b74e9ec4 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Got all the various checking stuff (e.g., Main Thread Checker) turned on?  With mysterious crashes on background threads, I'm usually suspicious that something invalid is going on with synchronization.

Comment: I don't have this crash on my devices. Yes they are turned on.